# Websockets service crashes after unexpected closing connections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an Asp.Net MVC backend and a mobile application (cordova).
I added a websockets service to backend using [this library](https://github.com/radu-matei/websocket-manager) as starting point.

Websockets service crashes if client disconnects very often without normal closing connection (just close application). Usually three times enough for reproducing.

I added try-catch block to [this function](https://github.com/radu-matei/websocket-manager/blob/master/src/WebSocketManager/WebSocketManagerMiddleware.cs#L23) and it works fine for one unexpectedly closed connection.

After reproducing service responses "503 Service Unavailable" some times, after that works fine.

I added try-catch to all functions and use ILooger object in catch block for logging but I don't see errors in logs and on Azure portal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved a websockets code to a separate app service and it works fine. I use sevice bus for communication between a general service and the websockets service.